# Why is $ \mathbb{N} $ a fine moduli space for the moduli problem of finite sets up to bijection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, moduli-space

How to establish rigourously that $ \mathbb{N} $ is a fine moduli space for the moduli problem of finite sets up to bijection ?.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? Do you have a candidate for the universal family? Be sure you understand the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_space#Fine_moduli_spaces

Comment: If i'm not wrong, we need to show that : $ \mathbb{N} $ represent a functor $ F $ definded by : $ \ F(T) = \{ \ \ \text{finite sets} \ \ X \ \ \mathrm{over} \ \  T \ \} / \sim_{\mathrm{bij}} $, isn't it ?

Comment: I think that $F(T)$ is bundles of finite sets over T, up to fiberwise bijection. To show that it $\mathbb{N}$ represents this functor, you need to produce an element of $F(\mathbb{N})$, the universal family / universal element, so that for every bundle $X$ over $T$, there is a unique function from $T$ to the natural numbers so that when you pull back the universal family you get something fiberwise bijective to $X$. There is really only one guess (up to fiberwise bijection) for a bundle of sets to put over $\mathbb{N}$, if you want to make sure that every isomoprhism type appears in a fiber.

Comment: This conception of ${\mathbb N}$ is really cute!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AreaMan already wrote the answer in the comments but let's be explicit.

Let $U = \{(n,m) \in \Bbb N^2 : 1 \leq m \leq n \}$. I claim that $U$ is the universal family with $p : U \to \Bbb N$ being the projection onto the first coordinate.

Now let $f : X \to S$ a family of finite sets, i.e $f^{-1}(s)$ is finite for all $s \in S$. I can consider the map $g : S \to \Bbb N, s \mapsto |f^{-1}(s)|$. It is clear that *up to a fiberwise bijection* the pullback of $U$ by $g$ is $X$, as you can easily check from the definition. This is just a fancy way of saying that if we look at the set $ g^*U := \{ (s,u) \in S \times U : g(s) = p(u)\}$ then we have a natural bijection $g^*U \cong X$.

So every family $X \to S$ is naturally equivalent to a morphism $g : S \to \Bbb N$, i.e we have a natural isomorphism $F(S) \cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Set}}(S, \Bbb N)$, and this exactly means that $\Bbb N$ is a fine moduli space for the moduli problem of finite sets up to bijection.